# julia probability password only numbers

Tags: passwords, julia, probability

new to julia and trying to figure out this probability/proportion code.

The folowing code takes 10^6 passwords and counts what proportion have 1 or less lower case letters.

```
passLength = 8
numToCheck = 1
possibleChars = ['a':'z';'A':'Z';'0':'9']
#Define a function  that  counts  how  characters  are  lower  case
numLowerCaseChars(str) = sum([ islower(char) for  char in str])
n = 10^6

passwords = [String(rand(possibleChars ,passLength )) for _ in 1:n]
proportion = sum([ numLowerCaseChars(p)  <= numToCheck  for p in  passwords])/n
```

I need to alter this code to give me what proportion of passwords consist of solely numbers.

I already know the exact probability is 4.580010609233563e-7 which I've worked out by hand but i cant figure out how to get the same result with this code.

So far I've tried

```
passLength = 8
numToCheck = 8
possibleChars = ['a':'z';'A':'Z';'0':'9']
#Define a function  that  counts  how  many characters are integers
numintegers(str) = sum([ isnumber(char) for  char in str])
n = 10^6

passwords = [String(rand(possibleChars ,passLength )) for _ in 1:n]
proportion = sum([numintegers(p)  == numToCheck  for p in  passwords])/n
```

But this returns 1.0e-6 which is way different. Is this to do with the sample size? I've tried generating more that 10^6 passwords but julia stops working.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: `sum(all.(isdigit, x)) / length(x)`, where `x` is `Vector{String}` of passwords (unless I've misunderstood the question)

Comment: Is this homework?  Fine if it is — but it's helpful to know how much the answers should be leading.  It's worth thinking about what the possible answers might be with 10^6 samples.  What would the proportion be if 10 of your samples had all digits?

Comment: 1.0e-6 means one sample met the criterion. That’s not unlikely given that you expect about 0.5. (In other words: yes, it’s to do with the sample size.)

Comment: You can also optimize your code a bit by simply removing the `[ ]` brackets inside the sum expressions.  Just `sum(isnumber(char) for char in str)` is much more efficient.  You also don't need to store that list of passwords — just generate them and count their digits all in the same loop/generator/comprehension.